# Add key/value on array object with map

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, akita

I would add a key value/value on my array objects "members".

I am on React JS with Akita.

```
addAge(): Observable<Member[]> {
return this.selectAll().pipe(
                map((allMembers) => ({...allMembers, age:10}))
            )
}
```

-

```
 dataQuery.addDatasWeek().subscribe(res => {
                this.setState({obj: res})
            })
```

I hope for membersWithAge :

```
[{id: 5, name: "Teddy, age: 10}, {id: 6, name: "Toto", age: 10},...]
```

but...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding age to the allMembers object, you need to add it to each member inside allMembers.

```
addAge(): Observable < Member[] > {
  return this.selectAll().pipe(
    map((allMembers) => allMembers.map(member => ({
      ...member,
      age: 10
    })))
  )
}
```